# Custom runserver command gets 404 on static files

Tags: python, django

I try to add custom ascii logo into console output when starting django server, problem is that my static files gets 404.What i do:

I create custom run (runserver) command at

app/managment/commands/run.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.core.management.commands import runserver 

LOGO = """
    >>ASCII LOGO<<<
"""

class Command(runserver.Command):
    def inner_run(self, *args, **options):
        self.stdout.write(LOGO)
        super(Command, self).inner_run(self, *args, **options)

# Kept for backward compatibility
BaseRunserverCommand = Command
```

i run

```
 python manage.py run
```

server starts, everything is fine, then i get

```
[08/Dec/2015 19:46:02] "GET /monitor/board HTTP/1.1" 200 6911
Not Found: /static/js/plugins/masonry.pkgd.min.js
[08/Dec/2015 19:46:02] "GET /static/js/plugins/masonry.pkgd.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 2803
Not Found: /static/js/custom/board.js
[08/Dec/2015 19:46:02] "GET /static/js/custom/board.js HTTP/1.1" 404 2767
```

but when i run it with

```
python manage.py runserver
```

stataic loads ok

```
[08/Dec/2015 19:49:25] "GET /monitor/board HTTP/1.1" 200 6911
[08/Dec/2015 19:49:25] "GET /static/js/custom/board.js HTTP/1.1" 200 147
[08/Dec/2015 19:49:25] "GET /static/js/plugins/masonry.pkgd.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 28953
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `staticfiles` app uses a custom `runserver` command to serve static files in development. To maintain this behaviour, you need to subclass that command instead:

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.management.commands import runserver 

LOGO = """
    >>ASCII LOGO<<<
"""

class Command(runserver.Command):
    def inner_run(self, *args, **options):
        self.stdout.write(LOGO)
        super(Command, self).inner_run(self, *args, **options)

# Kept for backward compatibility
BaseRunserverCommand = Command
```